# Keep Gerbils Quiet

Tags: rodents, gerbil

What is an appropriate way to keeping gerbils quiet?

They make to much noise and I live in a small space I am not sure what to do.

It keeps me from sleeping.  Are there soundproof cages maybe?

Answer (score 4):

What noise are they making? If it is the wheel they have you could get a silent spinner. You could also try using another sound to drown them out. Maybe some light music. Or a fan. 
Also if the cage is light consider moving the location of it at night. Maybe place it in the bathroom. So you don't have to mess with their sleep pattern and they won't mess with yours.
Even a clear safe space in a closet for night time.